# Zoom issue QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I am trying to zoom in with a scale between 1 and 10 in a QGraphicsView. The code I have is complex but I created a minimal reproducible example as follows:

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWin;
    mainWin.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

CustomGraphicsView.h
#include

```
class CustomGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
public:
    CustomGraphicsView(QGraphicsScene* scene, QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QGraphicsView(scene, parent) {}

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override;
    inline void setSceneSize(int origX, int origY, int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        m_SceneOrigX = origX;
        m_SceneOrigY = origY;
        m_SceneSizeX = sizeX;
        m_SceneSizeY = sizeY;
    }

   void resize();

private:
     int m_SceneOrigX = -1;
     int m_SceneOrigY = -1;
     int m_SceneSizeX = -1;
     int m_SceneSizeY = -1;
 };
```

CustomGraphicsView.cpp

```
#include "customgraphicsview.h"

void CustomGraphicsView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    fitInView(m_SceneOrigX, m_SceneOrigY, m_SceneSizeX, m_SceneSizeY, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event); 
}

void CustomGraphicsView::resize()
{
    fitInView(m_SceneOrigX, m_SceneOrigY, m_SceneSizeX, m_SceneSizeY, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "customgraphicsview.h"
#include <QSlider>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();

private slots:
    void showItems();
    void setZoomLevel(int zoom);

private:
    QGraphicsScene* m_Scene;
    CustomGraphicsView* m_View;
    QWidget* m_MainView;
    QSlider* m_ZoomSlider;
    double m_CurrentZoomLevel = 1.0;
};
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>


 MainWindow::MainWindow()

{
setMinimumHeight(600);
setMinimumWidth(800);

m_Scene = new QGraphicsScene();
m_View = new CustomGraphicsView(m_Scene);
m_View->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AlwaysShowToolTips);

m_MainView = new QWidget();
m_ZoomSlider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
m_ZoomSlider->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
m_ZoomSlider->setTickPosition(QSlider::TicksAbove);
m_ZoomSlider->setMinimum(1);
m_ZoomSlider->setMaximum(10);
m_ZoomSlider->setTickInterval(1);

QVBoxLayout* vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
vLayout->addWidget(m_View);
vLayout->addWidget(m_ZoomSlider);
m_MainView->setLayout(vLayout);

setCentralWidget(m_MainView);

connect(m_ZoomSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, &MainWindow::setZoomLevel);

showItems();

}

void MainWindow::showItems() {

m_Scene->clear();
m_View->resetTransform();
m_Scene->setSceneRect(QRectF());
m_View->setSceneRect(QRectF());
m_View->fitInView(QRectF());

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    int row = i % 3;
    int col = i / 3;
    QGraphicsRectItem* squareItem = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 3000 * 1000, 3000 * 1000);
    m_Scene->addItem(squareItem);
    squareItem->setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::black), 10000));
    squareItem->setPos((col - 1) * 3000 * 1000, (row - 1) * 3000 * 1000);
    
}

m_Scene->setSceneRect(-3000 * 1000, -3000 * 1000, 4 * 3000 * 1000, 4 * 3000 * 1000);
m_View->setSceneSize(-3000 * 1000 / m_CurrentZoomLevel, -3000 * 1000 / m_CurrentZoomLevel, 4 * 3000 * 1000 / m_CurrentZoomLevel, 4 * 3000 * 1000 / m_CurrentZoomLevel);
}


void MainWindow::setZoomLevel(int zoom) {
    m_CurrentZoomLevel = zoom;
    showItems();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
project (ZoomTestProject CXX)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS 1)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core Widgets)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0020 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0043 NEW)

include_directories(
    ${Qt6Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Qt6Core_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(DOCK_SRCS 
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    customgraphicsview.cpp
 )

set(DOCK_HEADR
    mainwindow.h
    customgraphicsview.h
 )

 add_executable(ZoomTestProject 
     ${DOCK_SRCS}
    ${DOCK_HEADR})

 target_link_libraries(ZoomTestProject
     Qt6::Widgets
     Qt6::Core)


set(ROOT_PATH ${Qt6_DIR}/../../../)

install(TARGETS ZoomTestProject DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES ${ROOT_PATH}/bin/Qt6Core.dll DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES ${ROOT_PATH}/bin/Qt6Gui.dll DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES ${ROOT_PATH}/bin/Qt6Widgets.dll DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES ${ROOT_PATH}/plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll DESTINATION bin/platforms)
```

The problem that I have is that when I zooming in , when I move the slider the first time to a zoom level, it zooms correctly (scroll bars are correctly positioned, the size of the shown elements is correct). When I move the slider again it zooms to a very big level, the scroll bars are not correct anymore. If I move the slider further nothing happens anymore, the extreme zoom level remains, the scroll bars keep their false size.

Does anyone have an idea about what this can be ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this as follows:

1. Do not call fitinView inside the resize event of the customgraphicsview
2. Implement a function called resize in the customgraphicsview as follows:

   void CustomGraphicsView::resize()
   {
   fitInView(m_SceneOrigX, m_SceneOrigY, m_SceneSizeX, m_SceneSizeY, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
   }
3. In the showItems() function of mainwindow do at the end as follows:

   m_Scene->setSceneRect(-3000 * 1000, -3000 * 1000, 4 * 3000 * 1000, 4 * 3000 * 1000);
   m_View->scale(m_ScaleFactor, m_ScaleFactor);
   m_View->setSceneSize(-3000 * 1000 / m_CurrentZoomLevel, -3000 * 1000 / m_CurrentZoomLevel, 4 * 3000 * 1000 / m_CurrentZoomLevel, 4 * 3000 * 1000 / m_CurrentZoomLevel);
   m_View->resize();
4. The setZoomLevel() function in the mainwindow was changed as follows:

   void MainWindow::setZoomLevel(int zoom) {
   m_ScaleFactor = double(zoom) / m_CurrentZoomLevel;
   m_CurrentZoomLevel = zoom;
   showItems();
   }

The essence of the problem is that fitInView call when resizing of customgraphicsview does not work with the zoom function. I have read in other threads that a solution to this would be to always show the scrollbars in the view. I tried this as well but did not bring any results.
I hope this helps someone in need.